# Is it Possible to use PerformancePoint Services in FBA Site?

Tags: 2010, development, sharepoint-enterprise

I have followed [`this`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386150/SharePoint-2010-Performance-Point-Service-Configur) article to activate Performance Point Services in Central administration. I have activated all the features of Performance Point Service in SiteCollection level as well as Web level..

Now when I open `Dashboard designer`,I am getting an error - mentioned below :

**An error has occured attempting to contact the specified sharepoint site. please check your connection and setting and try again**

My web-application is `Claims based authentication(fba)` but it is working in `classic mode Authentication(Window)`.

My doubt: is it possible to make Performance Point Services work in FBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have multiple AuthN providers on your Web Application? If so, you need to extend your web app to a new zone and only have Windows AuthN on that one.

Comment: hi..i dnt know related administrator side.but if i extend application..is this able to use by active directory user that webapplication?

Comment: that's exactly what you need to do - use windows authn